# How to interpret [73] at end of an xml2 error message

Tags: r, xml2

I am using R to parse 60 large (0.5 GB each) XML files from the same source. I have code that works for all file except one, which returns this error message:

```
Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  expected '>' [73]
```

This comes from `read_xml.character()`.

The message is clear that there is a missing character in the file, but to help me find it it would be goo to know: what does the `[73]` refer to?

(My first guess was line 73 of the file, but there's nothing obviously wrong with that).

I can't post a reproducible example because of the size of the file and its commercial in confidence; so I'd be happy just with a point on the error message.

Comment: OK, assuming GT means 'greater than' symbol, that answers my question - 73 just means "XML error, 'greater than' symbol (ie >) is required", which is what was provided by the R error. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: For the record, the file was just generally corrupt, and the lack of a > sign was just the first symptom. I re-downloaded it from source and it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R package `xml2` is basically a wrapper for the [libxml2 parser](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). The `libxml2` library defines a bunch of [error codes](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html). Here's a subset of those codes:

```
XML_ERR_PUBID_REQUIRED = 71 : 71
XML_ERR_LT_REQUIRED = 72 : 72
XML_ERR_GT_REQUIRED = 73 : 73
XML_ERR_LTSLASH_REQUIRED = 74 : 74
XML_ERR_EQUAL_REQUIRED = 75 : 75
```

So the number you see in the bracket in R is the error code returned from the xmllib2 library. In this case error 73 meas that a greater than symbol (GT) was expected but not found.

Since this doesn't tell you exactly where the error occurred, you might want to use an xml validator to get more diagnostic information about what exactly happened in the file.